# How to find a name with the fourth highest score?

Tags: python

pardon this silly question but I need your help.

I have a list of name, let's say

> name = ['Alpha','Betta','Chroma','Delta','Echo', 'Froyo']

and their scores are

> score = [75,60,80,79,90,30]

How to write the code in Python so if I want to know the fourth highest score the result is

> The fourth highest score is Alpha.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way :

```
sorted(zip(score, name), reverse=True)[3]
```

output:

```
>> (75, 'Alpha')
```

Comment: Nobody likes negative indexes? :-(

Comment: @KellyBundy well, maybe due to readability!  idk , nothing wrong with negative indexes though ;)

Comment: I find `-4` for "**four**th highest" very readable. And without the `, reverse=True` it would also be *less* to read...

Comment: I agree with Kelly here. "Fourth from highest" `sorted(...)[-4]` speaks to me a lot better than  "Fourth index from the reversed order using zero-based indexing `sorted(...,reverse...)[3]`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer is to use a dictionary. A dictionary is better than two lists because it only uses one variable, and scores are tied to their name so you don't have to maintain matching indexes. This answer is assuming you are using python 3.7 or newer.`sorted_scores` contains  sorted list of tuples structured `(name,points)`.

```
scores = {
    "Alpha" : 75,
    "Betta" : 60,
    "Chroma" : 80,
    "Delta" : 79,
    "Echo" : 90,
    "Froyo" : 50
}
sorted_scores = sorted(scores.items(),key=lambda item: item[1])
print(f"The fourth highest score is {sorted_scores[-4][0]} with {sorted_scores[-4][1]} points.")
#reason for -4 is that sorted() returns the list lowest to highest, and -4 is the fourth from the end. To have higher scores at the top, add reverse=True as a parameter of sorted() and replace -4 with 3.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I found that this is to find the fourth list from the top, not the fourth highest. Hence, if the score is 100, 100, 90, 80, 79, and so on, the code will result 80, not 79.

Comment: I believe that is what this code already does. I set it to the values in your comment and it returned Delta with 80 points.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `nlargest` function from the `heapq` module:

```
from heapq import nlargest

name = ['Alpha','Betta','Chroma','Delta','Echo', 'Froyo']
score = [75,60,80,79,90,30]

*_,(_,fourth) = nlargest(4,zip(score,name)) # name of last of top 4

print(fourth) # Alpha
```